# Filter Entity reference based on attribute

Tags: entities, users, input-formats

Here's my situation: I have a "Project" content type. I want to be able to add employees to a project based on their role with a select or multi-select drop down widget with unlimited number of values. So I can add multiple people with different roles.

I would like to be able to choose a Role first - say a "designer" - and then have the drop down for the entity reference only show just the roles for designers.

```
Project
  --> choose Role "designer"
  --> choose designer "John Doe"
  Add next person
  --> choose Role "??"
  --> choose person "??"
```

What are possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found offering a very high amount of flexibility is to combine the two following components:

- The [Dynamic Dependent Fields (DDF) module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf) takes in charge the relation between the other fields composing your form and your Entity Reference field.

  Concretely, it will add a new mode for the entity selection, "*Views: Filter by an entity reference view with dynamic argument*", which allows you to dynamically pass the value of one or several other fields of your edit form as contextual filters to a view.

  The magic here is that the values proposed by your Entity Reference is dynamically updated upon modification of the controller fields content (JavaScript).

  The only limitations I encountered with this module is that it does not support autocomplete fields as the controlee Entity Reference fields, drop-down lists must be used instead. Moreover, DDF does not take into account programmatically set default values for the controller fields, however [I submitted a patch solving this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2572543).
- [A patch for Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/node/2010898) (currently in RTBC status) adds the possibility to use tokens now as contextual filter for the views and complement very well the above mentioned DDF module.

  For instance, this patch allows very easily to exclude the current entity from the Entity Reference available choices.

Associating the two modules let your Entity Reference fields available values to be generated by a View taking into account both tokens and other fields values. Hard to get more flexibility !

Answer (score 1):

you can't use  **Hierarchical select** [Hierarchical Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module for this purpose because you don't have dependancy like Countyr -> State -> City -> Village etc.  so you should create view for your content type and add expose filter manually like :

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter().
*/
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form' && $form_state['view']->name == 'my_view_name' && $form_state['view']->current_display == 'my_view_display_name') {
// your stuff here 
       if(isset($_POST['project_name'] && !empty($_POST['project_name']))
        {
        }
       ...
        and so on..

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you post, this sounds a lot more complicated than I was hoping.

Comment: Thanks for your post, this sounds a lot more complicated than I was hoping. I was hoping I could just do what a page view does when filtering.  It just gives a drop down to filter all the users by role. Is there a better solution for what I need, the Hierarchical select is the function I want, but I need it to link to the actual user.

Comment: it is not complicated i have worked on these type of filters..i will send you full code but before this you should send full description of what you want...!

Answer (score 0):

[Hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf) Module provides input format similar for your requirement.

> **Description**
>
> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.
>
> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a
>   selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to
>   force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or
>   allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be
>   labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be
>   selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide
>   animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels
>   through Hierarchical Select!

Since hierarchical select will not work another way is by using
[Dynamic dependent fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/ddf), [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference), [Role field](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_field), [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) these modules.

Create a Field Collection with role field and user entity reference field and use DDF for filtering user entity reference by roles. Add this Field Collection to your project content type.

Comment: Thanks for your post, this sounds a lot more complicated than I was hoping. I was hoping I could just do what a page view does when filtering.  It just gives a drop down to filter all the users by role. Is there a better solution for what I need, the Hierarchical select is the function I want, but I need it to link to the actual user.

Comment: The subject matter doesn't deal with hierarchical vocabularies so HS doesn't make any sense here.